# How to define remote calls in julia?

Tags: julia, distributed

Please guide in defining remote call function:

log:

```
[root@srvr0 ~]# julia -p 4
               _
   _       _ _(_)_     |  Documentation: https://docs.julialang.org
  (_)     | (_) (_)    |
   _ _   _| |_  __ _   |  Type "?" for help, "]?" for Pkg help.
  | | | | | | |/ _` |  |
  | | |_| | | | (_| |  |  Version 1.6.4 (2021-11-19)
 _/ |\__'_|_|_|\__'_|  |  Official https://julialang.org/ release
|__/                   |

julia> 

julia> using Distributed;

julia> r = remotecall(2, ones, 2, 2)
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching remotecall(::Int64, ::typeof(ones), ::Int64, ::Int64)
Closest candidates are:
  remotecall(::Any, ::Distributed.LocalProcess, ::Any...; kwargs...) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/Distributed/src/remotecall.jl:357
  remotecall(::Any, ::Distributed.Worker, ::Any...; kwargs...) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/Distributed/src/remotecall.jl:363
  remotecall(::Any, ::Integer, ::Any...; kwargs...) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/Distributed/src/remotecall.jl:376
  ...
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope
   @ REPL[2]:1

julia> fetch(r)
ERROR: UndefVarError: r not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope
   @ REPL[3]:1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the type signature in the error message ("Closest candidates") indicates, the worker process must be the second argument to the call. So the function you're calling, `ones` in this case, is the first argument instead.

```
julia> using Distributed

julia> r = remotecall(ones, 2, 2, 2)
Future(2, 1, 5, nothing)

julia> fetch(r)
2×2 Matrix{Float64}:
 1.0  1.0
 1.0  1.0
```

Comment: Not having used `remotecall` ever, I must admit that this is a surprising calling convention, separating the function from the arguments... `@spawnat` seems a bit more natural. Is there a difference?

Comment: @phipsgabler I think it's a compromise between the arguments having to be last (because we don't know their number) and the Julia convention of putting the function argument first (makes it convenient for `do` syntax, `@chain`-like functionality, etc.). `@spawnat` seems to ultimately call `remotecall` itself, so yeah that makes for a nicer syntax when you know the function name in advance.

Comment: Ah, indeed, and as you can't put the process arg after the splat args, there is no other choice left. Makes sense.